# UIlabels initialized elsewhere besides .storyboard (Outlet reference) or and alloc int in view did load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, uilabel, xcode-storyboard

I have a UI that was made using code only pretty much: everything (UIlabels, etc) are initialized within viewdidload of the view controller.

.h

```
@interface homeViewController : UIViewController {

    //IBOutlet UILabel *lbl; // not using an outlet anyway...
    UILabel *lbl; 
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lbl;



@end
```

.m

```
@interface homeViewController ()

@end

@implementation homeViewController

@synthesize lbl;



-(void)updateLabel {


    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    double temptemp2 = [ud doubleForKey:@"somekey"];

    lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", temptemp2]; 

    [ud synchronize];


}
```

then in the viewdidload i just call [self updateLabel]; and the label does not get updated. however, if I put the same code that's inside updateLabel method into view did load, the code works.

the UIlabel is being initialized (alloc init) ahead of the [self updateLabel]; inside of view did load .

How should I initialize the label object properly if I do not want to do it using interface builder? so that it is accessible form other methods inside of the same view controller?

Comment: Can you show your code from `viewDidLoad` where you alloc/init your UILabel and where you add it as a subview?

Comment: sure! here it is: https://pastee.org/2y3fm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a @property on your view controller for the label, however when you create the label you are assigning it to a local variable instead of the property.  Because of this you are unable to reference it later from your other method when you want to assign the value.

In your `viewDidLoad`, assign the UILabel object you have created to the property like this:

```
self.lbl = lbl;
```

Then in your `updateLabel` method:

```
self.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", temptemp2];
```